# Are there any embeddable browsers available for WinRT?

Tags: browser, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

The html + css standards difficulties of supporting IE as a browser translate into using it as part of the WebView control where there are further limitations on functionality.

Other difficulties include:

***It renders on top of the XAML***
 - Using the recommended approach of WebViewBrush isn't a valid scenario if your pages have dynamic content on them.

***It doesn't support HTML5***

***You can't access the content***

***You can't access the content***
- Trying to debug issues with it is nigh on impossible.

Are there any alternative embeddable browsers available or in the works?

Comment: what limitations are your trying to work around?  webkit-specific behavior?  I wouldn't anticipate other browsers being supported - too much of a security risk to the sandboxed model of Windows Store app.

Comment: The web content that I need to render is also displayed on the iPad. Ideally this needs to be the same content on WinRT without changes. Additionally IE doesn't seem to work with any of the javascript gesture libraries available at the moment. I assume this is because the gestures are built-in system wide and aren't configurable.

Comment: The ideal way to go for Windows 8 touch in HTML/JS is via [Pointer Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/), that said if the libraries (is Hammer one?) are written to pre "Pointer" standards, I'd think they'd work for IE or could be made to. If they are relying on webkit-specific features, then I suppose I might be a harder climb, but not impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, I think Jim is correct that there are no other embeddable browsers available, and it's not something I'd expect to see.

I would also recommend that you review the [Windows Store Certification requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx), as many may be applicable in this case, including:

- 2.4 "The primary experiences your app provides must take place within the app" (as opposed to coming from the web)
- 3.6 "Your app must fully support touch input, and fully support keyboard and mouse input" which covers requirements for touch, including the need for your app's touch support to be consistent with the Windows 8 touch language.

While it's obviously appealing to re-use content across platforms, it's also important to keep in mind that this may lead to degraded experiences for end-users. If those experiences are too far afield of the established behaviors for Windows Store apps, they could also result in your app failing store certification.

For more info on Windows Store app development, register for [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Comment: A fair point, in this particular case the app is a sales tool with a focus on content syncing and offline viewing. Web content is just one of many types of content available.